# Print Multiple files using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, printing

Currently I creating result making Software in codeigniter in it I like to print Multiple result or multiple urls like

```
127.0.0.1/result/1
127.0.0.1/result/2
127.0.0.1/result/3
127.0.0.1/result/4
```

in one single button click
I search so much in google but i can't find good answer

any body can help me

I also use javascript like

```
window.print("127.0.0.1/result/1");
```

but it is only printing current page not result page

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Please clarify your question. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I tried javascript but javascript not creating & printing url

Comment: Please add the javascript code to the question.

Comment: In My Result Making Software I add all Marks & Grades when i open http://127.0.0.1/result/1 it shows first number student's result & on ctrl+p it print it but i want to print all 100 result on one click

Answer (score 0):

Use `CURL`, and by hitting `curl`, you will find all html content into a variable , similarly, hit `curl` for all urls and get html content, now you can merge all or print all.